# Python SDK list_shares does not return all shares

Tags: python, python-3.x, smartsheet-api

This code:

```
action = smartsheet.Sheets.list_shares(org_sheet.id,
                                       include_all=True)
shares = action.result
    for item in shares:
        print(item)
```

returns only two of the three users shared to the specific sheet.
This is not always the case, but I'm still investigating.

For this specific case, there are 2 shares to the workspace, one is shown. The other share is sheet specific.

I'm using Python 3.5 and the Python SDK 2.0

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how the items in the Workspace are shared they may not appear in the list when doing a request for the Workspace shares. Making that request will only return the email addresses of the users who are shared to the whole Workspace. Users that are shared to specific sheets without being given access to the entire Workspace won't appear in the list in the response.